# Multiple JavaScript-ViewModels on SinglePage-Site, Variable-Naming-Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am working on a single-page-application. For this purpose, I am using Knockout.js, which is really great for this task.

Now I'm facing a problem: The content of the pages is appended with jQuerys append-function. When i append two detail-pages from the same template, i have a conflict with my viewmodel-object-names, since both declare it's offlineDemoDetailViewModel-variable under use of the same name.

*TestDetailA (from TestDetail Template):  offlineDemoDetailViewModel = offlineDemoDetailViewModel();
TestDetailB (from TestDetail Template):  offlineDemoDetailViewModel = offlineDemoDetailViewModel();*

What is the best way to handle this? Should i create the variable-name dynaically or is there a better way?

Thanks a lot!

Just for Info, here is my (test) offlineDemoDetailViewModel-code:

```
var offlineDemoDetailViewModel = function () {
    var _viewmodel = new (function() {
        this.uuid = ko.observable(localDatabase.createUUID());
    });

    return _viewmodel;
};
```

Comment: Can you put a JSFiddle together?

Comment: Its pretty hard to do that in a fiddle -it would be very long. The answer is simple: The best way to do this is creating the variable dynamically and use the tab key in the name, so the variable is still unique after more than one viewmodel. Thanks!